# Under what circumstances can a Magento Order Increment ID have duplicates?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I've been running into some odd problems of late with a Magento installation (1.4.2.0), whereby the same order increment ID is being reused for more than one order.

[Screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/15z3o861w/)

As you can see in the screenshot above, a full 45 minutes pass before the same customer makes a second order with different products and total value, only to have the increment ID reused.

This also happens occasionally where the orders are a couple of minutes apart, which could possibly be from a double submission on a payment gateway causing two callbacks to Magento.

I'm keen to get some insight on how these things could happen, as I would expect each order to be given a unique ID - under what circumstances can we get duplicate order increment IDs?

Comment: thanks for posting such intermittent bugs, caused by some novice developer(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess would be there's a third party extension, core hack, or maybe even core code, that isn't handling operations with the Order objects transactionally.  That, combined with an unexpected exceptions somewhere between saving an order and the internal increment number being increased, could result in orders with the same number being created.  I'd check your Error and Exception logs for problems, clean those problems up, and see if the problem continues.

Otherwise you're going to need to reproduce the conditions of the errors in a test environment  and debug debug debug.

Comment: I haven't identified and fixed the specific cause of the problem yet, but the pattern in what we're seeing suggests this is being caused by a third party extension for a specific payment gateway. Sound advice, Alan - thanks!